# @click.stop events not firing in vue component in laravel/vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

All @click.stop events in my vue component wont fire and I can't see where I went wrong, I'm hoping another set of eyes can point out where I went wrong. I'm running npm run watch and I've cleared my cache.
Here is all the code you should need:

**My app.js**

```
window._ = require("lodash");

// window.Vue = require('vue');
import Vue from "vue";

window.axios = require("axios");

window.axios.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest";

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
  window.axios.defaults.headers.common["X-CSRF-TOKEN"] = token.content;
} else {
  console.error(
    "CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token"
  );
}

// const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i);
// files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default));

import VueSwal from "vue-swal";
Vue.use(VueSwal);

Vue.component(
  "example-component",
  require("./components/ExampleComponent.vue").default
);
//Vue.component('product-attributes', require('./components/ProductAttributes').default);

Vue.component(
  "attribute-values",
  require("./components/AttributeValues.vue").default
);

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
});
```

**My AttributeValues.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div id="">
    <div class="tile">
      <h3 class="tile-title">Attribute Values</h3>
      <hr />
      <div class="tile-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="value">Value</label>
          <input
            class="form-control"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter attribute value"
            id="value"
            name="value"
            v-model="value"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="price">Price</label>
          <input
            class="form-control"
            type="number"
            placeholder="Enter attribute value price"
            id="price"
            name="price"
            v-model="price"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tile-footer">
        <div class="row d-print-none mt-2">
          <div class="col-12 text-right">
            <button
              class="btn btn-success"
              type="submit"
              @click.stop="saveValue()"
              v-if="addValue"
            >
              <i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-check-circle"></i>Save
            </button>
            <button
              class="btn btn-success"
              type="submit"
              @click.stop="updateValue()"
              v-if="!addValue"
            >
              <i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-check-circle"></i>Update
            </button>
            <button
              class="btn btn-primary"
              type="submit"
              @click.stop="reset()"
              v-if="!addValue"
            >
              <i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-check-circle"></i>Reset
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
      <h3 class="tile-title">Option Values</h3>
      <div class="tile-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-sm">
            <thead>
              <tr class="text-center">
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Value</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Action</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr v-for="value in values">
                <td style="width: 25%" class="text-center">{{ value.id }}</td>
                <td style="width: 25%" class="text-center">
                  {{ value.value }}
                </td>
                <td style="width: 25%" class="text-center">
                  {{ value.price }}
                </td>
                <td style="width: 25%" class="text-center">
                  <button
                    class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"
                    @click.stop="editAttributeValue(value)"
                  >
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                  </button>
                  <button
                    class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"
                    @click.stop="deleteAttributeValue(value)"
                  >
                    <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                  </button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script type="application/javascript">
export default {
  name: "attribute-values",
  props: ["attributeid"],
  data() {
    return {
      values: [],
      value: "",
      price: "",
      currentId: "",
      addValue: true,
      key: 0,
    };
  },

  created: function () {
    this.loadValues();
  },

  methods: {
    loadValues() {
      let attributeId = this.attributeid;
      let _this = this;
      axios
        .post("/admin/attributes/get-values", {
          id: attributeId,
        })
        .then(function (response) {
          _this.values = response.data;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },

    saveValue() {
      if (this.value === "") {
        this.$swal("Error, Value for attribute is required.", {
          icon: "error",
        });
      } else {
        let attributeId = this.attributeid;
        let _this = this;
        axios
          .post("/admin/attributes/add-values", {
            id: attributeId,
            value: _this.value,
            price: _this.price,
          })
          .then(function (response) {
            _this.values.push(response.data);
            _this.resetValue();
            _this.$swal("Success! Value added successfully!", {
              icon: "success",
            });
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
      }
    },

    resetValue() {
      this.value = "";
      this.price = "";
    },

    reset() {
      this.addValue = true;
      this.resetValue();
    },

    editAttributeValue(value) {
      this.addValue = false;
      this.value = value.value;
      this.price = value.price;
      this.currentId = value.id;
      this.key = this.values.indexOf(value);
    },

    updateValue() {
      if (this.value === "") {
        this.$swal("Error, Value for attribute is required.", {
          icon: "error",
        });
      } else {
        let attributeId = this.attributeid;
        let _this = this;
        axios
          .post("/admin/attributes/update-values", {
            id: attributeId,
            value: _this.value,
            price: _this.price,
            valueId: _this.currentId,
          })
          .then(function (response) {
            _this.values.splice(_this.key, 1);
            _this.resetValue();
            _this.values.push(response.data);
            _this.$swal("Success! Value updated successfully!", {
              icon: "success",
            });
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
      }
    },

    deleteAttributeValue(value) {
      this.$swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this attribute value!",
        icon: "warning",
        buttons: true,
        dangerMode: true,
      }).then((willDelete) => {
        if (willDelete) {
          this.currentId = value.id;
          this.key = this.values.indexOf(value);
          let _this = this;
          axios
            .post("/admin/attributes/delete-values", {
              id: _this.currentId,
            })
            .then(function (response) {
              if (response.data.status === "success") {
                _this.values.splice(_this.key, 1);
                _this.resetValue();
                _this.$swal("Success! Option value has been deleted!", {
                  icon: "success",
                });
              } else {
                _this.$swal("Your option value not deleted!");
              }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
            });
        } else {
          this.$swal("Your option value not deleted!");
        }
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**Blade that has contains the  vue component**

```
 <div class="tab-pane" id="values">
   <attribute-values :attributeid="{{ $attribute->id }}"></attribute-values>
</div>

           
@endsection
        @push('scripts')
        <script type="application/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"> </script>
           
@endpush
```

**My Composer Json**

```json
{
  "name": "laravel/laravel",
  "type": "project",
  "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
  "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
  "license": "MIT",
  "require": {
    "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
    "laravel/framework": "^8.75",
    "laravel/helpers": "^1.5",
    "laravel/sanctum": "^2.11",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
    "laravel/ui": "^2.0",
    "typicms/nestablecollection": "*"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.10",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/",
      "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
      "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
      "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
      "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": ["@php artisan key:generate --ansi"]
  },
  "extra": {
    "laravel": {
      "dont-discover": []
    }
  },
  "config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "prefer-stable": true
}
```

**Package Json**

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "mix",
    "watch": "mix watch",
    "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
    "hot": "mix watch --hot",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "mix --production"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.43",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "popper.js": "^1.12",
    "postcss": "^8.1.14",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
    "sass": "^1.20.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.7",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue-swal": "^0.1.0"
  }
}
```

**There are no errors or warnings. Apart from this**

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
    <anonymous> http://127.0.0.1:8000/back-assets/js/index2.js:121
    jQuery 2
```

Any help would be appreciated, I hope I gave all the info you might need, if not, please ask.

Comment: you mean your `editAttributeValue` or `deleteAttributeValue` method is not called when you click on the button??

Comment: Yes thats correct. I have other methods too,  `saveValue`, `updateValue` ,`reset` non is being called.

Comment: what happen if you try with just `@click` event??

Comment: Make sure your click handler is on outer most element

Comment: @zahidhasanemon no change, still can trigger

Comment: @AliRaza how exactly do you mean pls?

Comment: you can trigger?? or can't?? what do you mean??

Comment: @zahidhasanemon I cant trigger

Comment: Firstly, your code could (and perhaps should) be simplified to [this](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/ogk2v6Lb/). Secondly, anyone trying to help would need to run the code in order to debug the issue and pinpoint the cause. Consider creating a *runnable* [mcve]. Note you can [import](https://codesandbox.io/docs/learn/getting-started/your-first-sandbox#import-local-projects-via-cli) your project into codesandbox in just a few steps.

Comment: Since you can't repro the backend in the sandbox, replace the `axios` calls with `Promise.resolve({ /* expected result here */ }).then(...` in the sandbox. Nobody else can do it, since we don't know how the responses look like.

Comment: Last, but not least, what exactly do you mean by a *"reputable source"*? Considering the nature of the bug, reputable sources are: [Vue documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html), the [HTML Standard](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-type-click) or an answer from a Vue core team member. The documentations are free to access. And the chances of a core Vue team member answering the question are close to `null`, at least on [SO].

Comment: You should take care of the exceptions thrown in index.js. The component code itself seems to be working (tried in my local environment). Check @tao:s answer for the simplications also.

Comment: Is Vue running on the page, can you do a console.log in the `created` hook? I don't see `<div id="app">` in your blade. Tested the vue component and thats working.

Answer (score 0):

Some tips, that can help you!

1. Make sure the scripts are included in your view, and are not conflicted.
2. remove unnecessary imports from your app.js
3. Make sure you really need to handle your button as submit. If you do not need that, you can stop submitting using, https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html
4. Try `@click="console.log('I can be triggered')` to see if you can trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit `@click.stop="Method()"`
to `@click.stop.prevent="Method()"`
And Try It